# How to view teammates' profiles before game starts?

Tags: dota-2

I played a game yesterday where someone was helping decide picks by looking at our profiles. For example, someone had a 0.05 versatility and so he asked the guy "so who's the one hero you play?" and the guy answered and changed his pick based on that question.

It was helpful for having everyone pick heroes that were best suited to their star chart summary.

But I can't figure out how to view other people's profile before the game starts.

How do I view my teammates profile before the game?

Comment: Your teammates question sounds strange. If he can see the "star chart" he can also check his recent games and see what heroes he played!?

Comment: Maybe he was being sarcastic :).

Comment: I am at work but i am pretty sure u can right-click your mates in the loadscreen and check them out.

Comment: @Opaldes You can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the loadscreen, you can click on their profile picture.

Then you can see their profile. The default tab selected is *Activity Feeds*, you can switch to *Recent Games* to see which heroes they did well with. On left side, the graph shows their strength.

**NOTE: the click works on profile picture only and not on player's name.**

Answer (score 1):

There are *some* addons that works good with Dota 2, **but yet they are not banned neither allowed**. For example, I heard about **Dota Plus** - this addon is based on dotabuff.com stats . Actually, it shows precise info about last 3 months and shows even **winrates** on top 3 heroes. Sometimes, you even can't get what role this guy wanna play, when you are checking his profile. As addition to all of this, it show who are **queued together** - it's actually useful too.

Comment: These aren't addons. It's a website that can analyze log files, but you have to visit the website, unless you are referring to a way to do this in-game

Comment: I'm referring to actually addons that work based on such sites :) just have seen a couple of friends using them - to show stats during loadscreen and pick inside the game.

Comment: Oh okay, interesting...